# Write to some fragment locations but not others

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

Currently, I have two shaders that are intended to process the same type of objects, but produce different output: one color for the screen, the other selection info.

Output of draw shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
```

Output of selection shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 selectionInfo0;
layout(location = 1) out ivec4 selectionInfo1;
```

I am considering combining the shaders together (these two and others in my application) for clarity and ease of maintenance (why edit two shaders when you can edit one?).

Output of unified shader:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 selectionInfo0;
layout(location = 2) out ivec4 selectionInfo1;
```

Under this scheme, I would set a uniform that determines which fragments need to be written to.

Can I write to some fragment locations and not others?

```
void main()
{
    if(Mode == 1){
        outColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else {
        selectionInfo0 = vec4(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4);
        selectionInfo1 = ivec4(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }
}
```

Is this a legitimate approach? Is there anything I should be concerned about?

Comment: Taken a look at what you've edited, and this approach is okay. *but*, still take a look at what I mentioned about branching in shader code. It's slow, so at the very least be aware of the concern of speed if you start adding more if statements since you want a 'one-shader for all' solution

Comment: Pasting the branch mention here because my answer was no longer relevant post-edit.-  "(why edit two shaders when you can edit one?)" is not always a good mindset. It's fine here but you shouldn't have one huge shader program to do all your different operations. Branching in shaders is very inefficient and slow, and should generally be avoided even if it means creating two seperate shaders for two different forms of functionality.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581719/opengl-glsl-uniform-branching-vs-multiple-shaders) a relevant question on that issue.

Comment: Hadn't seen that before, that's a really good link, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a legitimate approach?

That depends on how you define "legitimate". It can be made to *function*.

A fragment is either [discarded](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Discard) *in its entirety* or it is not. If it is discarded, then the fragment has (mostly) no effect. If it is not discarded, then all of its outputs either have defined values (ie: you wrote to them), or they have undefined values.

However, undefined values can be OK, depending on other state. For example, the [frambuffer's draw buffer state](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Draw_Buffer) routes FS output colors to actual color attachments. It can also route them to `GL_NONE`, which throws them away. Similarly, you can use [color write masks](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Write_Mask) on a per-attachment basis, turning off writes to attachments you don't want to write to.

But this means that you cannot determine it on a per-fragment basis. You can only determine this using state external to the shader. The FS can't make this happen or not happen; it has to be done between draw calls with state changes.

If `Mode` is some kind of `uniform` value, then that should be OK. But if it is something derived on a per-vertex or per-fragment basis, then this will not work effectively.

As for branching performance, again, that depends on `Mode`. If it's a `uniform`, you shouldn't be concerned at all. Modern GPUs can handle that just fine. If it is something else... well, your entire scheme stops working for reasons that have already been detailed, so there's no reason to worry about it ;)

That all being said, I would advise against this sort of complexity. It is a confusing way of handling things from the driver's perspective. Also, because you're relying on a lot of things that other applications are not relying on, you open yourself up to driver bugs. Your idea is different from a traditional Ubershader, because your options fundamentally change the nature of the render targets and outputs.

So I would suggest you try to do things in as conventional a way as possible. If you really want to minimize the number of separate *files* you work with, employ `#ifdef`s, and simply patch the shader string with a `#define`, based on the reason you're loading it. So you have one shader file, but 2 programs built from it.

Comment: `Mode` is a uniform. Duplicity of shader code (number of files) is one issue I am trying to solve. Another is duplicated application code that sets roughly the same uniforms when calling the two different programs. Can you say more about "It is a confusing way of handling things from the driver's perspective"?

Comment: @thethuthinnang: "*duplicated application code that sets roughly the same uniforms when calling the two different programs*" That's what Uniform Buffers are for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I always appreciate reading your answers.